# Uploading File to SharePoint from AWS Lambda Function

Tags: sharepoint, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function (currently Node.js, but could be turned into .NET Core) that runs on a schedule. I would like to, as part of its work, to upload a file to a SharePoint Online document library. What would be the best way to do this, especially considering authentication?

Comment: Hi, were you able to implement this?

Comment: Yes, using Graph API.

Comment: What is maximum file upload have you tried? Did you face any challenges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the Microsoft Graph APIs to upload files into Document Libraries of SharePoint Online

[Microsoft Graph: Uploading Files to SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Thanks, and how would you solve the authentication problem - connecting from an unauthenticated service?

Comment: [Daemon access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) auth is never easy ... 

The other option is the PNP Libraries for SharePoint are going to support .NET Core this month. These use CSOM/REST endpoints and do File Uploads.